# Upgrade Joomla from 1.5.17 to 2.5 by having only the old database

Tags: database, joomla, upgrade

I have an old database of Joomla 1.5.17. My site was hacked and the hosting provider insisted that I delete all the files from the server and installed the newest version of Joomla. Now I have the old database and I want to restore my site with Joomla 2.5. Is it posible at all? If, yes then how?

**EDIT:
Can't I just install new Joomla without creating a new database but using the old database. Why Joomla does not thought about such a feature??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a fresh copy of Joomla 1.5.26 (latest version), then import the database. Then download JUpgrade which will allow you to easily migrate to Joomla 2.5. Please do bare in mind that this will update default Joomla tables such as content, module positions and so on. It won't update your 3rd party extensions, so you will need to install the Joomla 2.5 compatible versions of them.

Hope this helps

Comment: JUpgrade is definitely the best way to do this. Since it sounds like your host doesn't want 1.5 installed on there, you could also do the upgrade on a localhost and then upload just the upgraded system.